# Xcode Localizable.string multiple targets issue

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I have a project with multiple targets, which represent the same app just with different styling and translations.

Since almost whole project looks the same for each target, I need to have just few strings in `Localizable.strings` file, that I need to be different. And I don't want to copy whole huge `Localizable.strings` file to each project just because of the fact it has few lines different.

It is required for me to have just 1 strings file because of third-party libraries/SDK that are included in project. So I cannot use `tableName` for `localizedString`.

The **problem** is - I need to have a flexible possibility to override just few lines from `Localizable.strings` for each target separately. And I don't like the idea just to copy whole file to each target, cause it will lead to annoying flow in the future, in case I will have 10 targets and I need to add 1 string to all of them.

The **goal** is to have 1 huge `Localizable.strings` file with all strings included, that would be common for all targets, and have small configuration for each target for the strings that should tell different. So target's file should kinda merge and override the one that is common.

AFAIK it is not natively supported by Xcode, so I'm probably looking for a script that would make it works.

So, script should look into common and target's Localizable files, merge them, and in case some keys are defined in both, then it should use the one from target's file.

Can anyone help me with such script?

---

P.S. Similar issue exists with `.xcassets`, and CocoaPods solves it by merging multiple assets into 1, and it works as expected - if some targets has an asset containing the image with the same name that is already included into a common asset, then the one from target will replace it.

P.S.2. Similar feature is natively supported for Android devs - each image, each translations can be overridden by "child" flawor, or whatever it is called :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **TL;DR:**

#### Example project: https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO45279964

---

OK, the easier thing to do would be shell/python script, because it will work for every build server. I assume that you have a different scheme for each target (otherwise it will make no sense). So what you can do is:

Let's say your target is named:

- target1
- target2
- target3

1) Create separate files contains all the strings that should be different (i will put it under `Localizable` directory.

Your Localizable.strings file may look like this:

```
"someGeneralString" = "General string 1";
"AppName" = "This is a string that you probably need to change";
"someOtherGeneralString" = "General string 2";
```

And any of your `targetX.strings` file may look like this:

```
"AppName" = "target[x]"
```

And here is how it should look like in your project:

[image]

**Note that your `target` localizable files should has target membership set only to one target, but your `Localizable.strings` should be for all targets!**

That's all for project configuration. Let's go to scripting (I will use python for that):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

supportedLanguages = ["en","pl"]
commonPath = ".lproj/Localizable.strings"
keys = ["AppName"]

    class CopyLocalizable():

        target = ""

        def __init__(self,arg):
            self.target = arg
            self.perform()

        def perform(self):
            for lang in supportedLanguages:
                pathToLocalizable = lang+commonPath
                textToFile = ""
                with open(pathToLocalizable,"r") as languageFile:          
                    for line in languageFile.readlines():
                        for key in keys:
                            if key in line:
                                textToFile += self.foundAndReplace(key,lang)
                            else:
                                textToFile += line
                self.saveInFile(pathToLocalizable,textToFile)


        def foundAndReplace(self,key,lang):
            pathToTargetFile = "Localizable/"+lang+".lproj/"+self.target+".strings"
            with open(pathToTargetFile,"r") as targetFile:
                for targetLine in targetFile.readlines():
                    if key in targetLine:
                        return targetLine

        def saveInFile(self,file,stringToSave):
            with open(file,"w+") as languageFile:
                languageFile.write(stringToSave)
```

You can optimize it yourself. It's easier script i can think about to get a job done.

And in the end let's automate it a bit:
 - Go to your target 
 - add a new build phase
 - Add a new script:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
cd SO45279964/
python localize.py target[x]
```

and watch a magic happen ;)

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/26n6NKgiwYvuQk7WU

Here you can find example project that I've created to run this example:
https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO45279964

Comment: Thanks, Kuba. Mostly working like I wanted. Few comments: **1.** As I understand we could even remove targetX files from the build, cause they anyway are not used in the project, cause we use the general localizable file. **2.** I will probably rewrite script to Ruby, which is more friendly to me and make it not contain hardcoded keys. But anyway, thanks for idea and example.

Comment: 1) Yes, this files has nothing to do with project.
2) Sure, as I wrote that's the simplest implementation of this. You can rewrite it (you should acctually ;) ) and there is also room for optimization here, because in above script, the file is reopened for every key.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, Have a Macro defined for each target in Build Settings & define target specific strings within macro section  like

```
#ifdef __TARGET__
//key values in localizable file
#endif
```